# check array is exist if yes then grab last element

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array as shown below, thing is i need to grab the last element from myarray=>dates[1]
but the thing is the dates sometime have multiple elements or sometime single element like in situation it has two.

**situation one**

```
myarray(1) {

 ["dates"]=>  array(2) { 
    [0]=>    string(29) "Tue, 26 Oct 2010 01:03:39 GMT" 
    [1]=>    string(2) "-1" 
  } 

}
```

**situation two**

```
myarray(1) {

     ["dates"]=> => Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
      } 

    }
```

here in second situation it is very easy i can grab it by myarray['dates'] but i am not sure how to do it in first situation..

Could any body please share some info.

Thank you

Mona

Comment: What do you want? I mean, either you want date or you want last element doesn't matter what it is?

Comment: [`is_array`](http://us2.php.net/is_array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get last element of an array use `end` function

```
    if(is_array($myarray['dates']))
    {
        echo end ( $myarray['dates'] )
    }else{
       echo $myarray['dates'] 
    }
```

see https://www.php.net/end

Comment: Great Harish, Thank you so much.. it worked like charm...something new i learned today 'end'...

Answer (score 0):

It's [is_array()](https://www.php.net/is_array) that you can use:

```
if(is_array($myarray['dates']))
{
   end($myarray['dates']);
   $result = $myarray['dates'][key($myarray['dates'])];
}
else
{
   $result = $myarray['dates'];
}
```